# How to combine two arrays of integers and return average?

Tags: c#

Ok so I have two arrays of integers, and I have to return the average rating of the two days. This is the code that I have come up with thus far, but apparently it does not meet the expectations. Result:

> Message:   Expected: 5.0d
>     But was:  3.0d

**Unit:**

```
public double WeekendAverage(int[] saturday, int[] sunday)
    {
        int[] n = { saturday.Length, sunday.Length };
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = saturday[i] + sunday[i];
            return sum / n.Length;
        }
        return sum;
        }
```

**UnitTest:**

```
[TestCase(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 10 }, new[] { 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10 }, 7)]

public void WeekendAverage(int[] saturday, int[] sunday, double expected)
    {
        var actual = warmups.WeekendAverage(saturday, sunday);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. Array `n` in your code will have only two values, length of Saturday array and length of Sunday array. It will not have the actual values from Saturday and Sunday. Also you are returning from for loop so the loop will be executed only once. You need make the logic clear and debug the code and see if it runs as per the logic. And correct it accordingly

Comment: running your test case code gives: Message:   Expected: 7.0d
  But was:  5.0d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without Linq. Just calculate the sum and divide with the length of the combined array.

```
public double WeekendAverage(int[] saturday, int[] sunday)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < saturday.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += saturday[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sunday.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += sunday[i];
    }
    return sum / (saturday.Length + sunday.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `System.Linq`

```
var saturday = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 10 };
var sunday = new[] { 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10 };

var average = saturday.Concat(sunday).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average();
```

Comment: Can be simplified to `saturday.Concat(sunday).Average()`

Comment: @AlphaDelta `saturday.Concat(sunday).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average()` is probably safer :)

Comment: Yes, right you are. The Average method will, however, return a double, so it depends on the requirements. I suppose they can also add Math.round if required.

Comment: @John Solid point, prevents an exception if both collections contain no items

Comment: Can also be extended with `params` and `SelectMany` to average an arbitrary amount of collections, see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FDnxiy

Comment: Thank you. I updated the answer to include your suggestions.

Comment: Is nice to see you can do it with linq, but as for being a beginner, I would also like to learn without linq.

Comment: 2 passed, but the first one gave me this Message:   Expected: 7.0d
  But was:  7.2000000000000002d

Comment: Could just be a project requirement issue.

Comment: Hi @AlexH, the Average() method will return a double, that's why you are getting the  message stated above, you can add Math.Round(saturday.Concat(sunday).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average())

Answer (score 0):

The length of n is 2 as an array. You want an int that stores the total of the two array lengths, not an array of integers representing the lengths of your parameters.

Change that to n = saturday.length + sunday.length and i < n in your loop.

Comment: How would I return sum?

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq (adapted from Theodor's answer) :

```
public double WeekendAverage(int[] saturday, int[] sunday)
{
    double sum = saturday.Sum() + sunday.Sum();
    return sum / (saturday.Length + sunday.Length);
}
```